# Need help understanding this proof that if $H=\{e, (1 \, 2)(3 \, 4), (1\, 3)(2 \, 4), (1 \, 4)(2\, 3)\}$, then it is a normal subgroup of $S_4$.

Tags: group-theory

I'm going to remove some of the details from the proof: If $(i \, j)$ is a transposition in $S_n$ and $\tau \in S_n$, then $\tau (i \, j)\tau^{-1} = (\tau(i) \, \tau(j))$ so for any two disjoint transpositions $(i\, j),(k\,l)$,  $$\tau(i\, j)(k\,l)\tau^{-1} = (\tau(i) \, \tau(j))(\tau(k) \,\tau(l)),$$ which is again a product of transpositions. Then it follows from the above that $\tau \, \sigma \,\tau^{-1} \in H$ for all $\sigma \in H$.

I don't understand how does it follow from the above result exactly that $\tau \, \sigma \,\tau^{-1} \in H$ for all $\sigma \in H$.

If someone feels I should fill in the details to the proof above, please leave a comment saying so.

Comment: Maybe simpler: conjugate elements of $S_n$ have the same cycle type. Your $H$ contains all elements of $S_4$ that have cycle type $(a\;b)(c\;d)$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Haven't studied that yet. Have to use results already known to us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us agree that if $\;\sigma\in S_n\;,\;\;i\in\{1,2,...,n\}\;$ , then $\;\sigma(i)\;$ is the image of $\;i\;$ under $\;\sigma\;$ .

Now, separating by cases if necessary, show that for any *$\;k$-cycle* $\;c:=(i_1\;i_2\;...i_k)\in S_n\;$ , we have that

$$\sigma c\sigma^{-1}=(\sigma(i_1)\;\sigma(i_2)\;\ldots\;\sigma(i_k))$$

and this proves $\;k$-cycles are invariant under conjugation. This proves Hagen's comment and gives you an almost complete answer to your question.